# removing affix with javascript in a array

Tags: javascript

where do we start if we want to remove the affix from this sentence **me**ang**an** **me**nang**kan** **di**menang**kan**

```
affix_list = [
'me-an',
'me-kan,
'di-kan
]

string = 'meangan menangkan dimenangkan'
```

so it will output

```
output = [
'ang',
'nang'
'menang'
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) for those replacements. Starting from your `affix_list`, this should work:

```
output = affix_list.reduce(function(str, affix) {
    var parts = affix.split("-");
    var regex = new RegExp("\\b"+parts[0]+"(\\S+)"+parts[1]+"\\b", "g");
    return str.replace(regex, "$1")
}, string).split(" ");
```

Your `regex`es will look like this:

```
/\bme(\S+)an\b/g
/\bme(\S+)kan\b/g
/\bdi(\S+)kan\b/g
```

But note that you will of course need to replace `me-kan` before `me-an`, else `"menangkan"` will become `nangk` before the `me-kan` expression can be applied.

Comment: Non-whitespice. If you would have used `.+` (or `.+?`), it might have removed the prefix of the first and the suffix of the last word.

Comment: @AdamRamadhan: No, `me-kan` should be the first (or at least before `me-an`) in the list of expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to start with Javascript regular expressions and iterate through the values, retrieving the middle value accordingly. I'll do that first one for you, and you can try out the rest :)

```
var re = /me(\w+)an/;
var str = "meangan";  
var newstr = str.replace(re, "$1");  
console.log(newstr);
// outputs ang
```

**Reference**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions